# Angularjs $state open link in new tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm trying to implement an "open link in new tab" function using $state.go function. It would be awesome if there was smth like:

```
$state.go('routeHere', {
    parameter1 : "parameter"
    }, {
    reload : true,
    newtab : true // or smth like target : "_blank"
});
```

Is there any way to do that using AngularJS?

Comment: The Edit in the question saying that you solved it with the following code seems redundant. Ie. it's implied by the fact that you chose it as your accepted answer.

Comment: Fixed, removed the edit.

Comment: You may find the answer here [Angularjs $state open link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565518/1959948)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Update: OK, I just solved it using the following code:

```
var url = $state.href('myroute', {parameter: "parameter"});
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be $window for best practice?

Comment: Are you sure the parameter can be passed to new window?

Comment: Yes @elaijuh they will be passed

Comment: @alex i want to target a defined window, so i tried window.open(url,'myWindow'); but it doesnt work. Any help?

Comment: Add a third parameter, something like: window.open(url, 'myWindow', "height=200,width=200"); Most probably it will work like this.

Comment: I am doing it in this way and all I get is a blank page. If I place the same url into Browser directly I am getting the correct results. Any idea?

Comment: By this approach state params are not receiving in new tab.
Could any one please help me with this?

Comment: Note that if you do open a link from javascript this way and that the base url changes, chances are the browser will block it saying the site tried to open a popup, but if user accepts or authorize your website to do so, then it will work.

Comment: Also if using coffeescript, add `return true` as well since it will add it as a DOM element other wise and throw an [error like this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4853)

Answer (score 55):

I just tried this -- apparently, adding `target="_blank"` works with `ui-sref`:

```
<a ui-sref="routeHere" target="_blank">A Link</a>
```

Saves the trouble of adding code to your controller, and gives you the URL on hover as with any normal link. Win-win!

Comment: this only works on an <a>. "target" doesn't work on other elements apparently. i.e <button ui-sref="routeHere" target="_blank">A Link</button>

Comment: @Luis Buttons dont have Target attribute so yes it wont work

Comment: @Luis Maybe you can use button related classes and role as button for anchor tag to make it look like a button. Eg.: `<a ui-sref="routeHere" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">A Link</a>`

Answer (score 7):

It may not work on localhost in the event your app is in a subfolder.
I had in fact the same issue.

I have tried online and it worked as expected by using:

```
<a ui-sref="routeHere" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue, try this if nothing from previous answers work for you.

```
var url = '#' + $state.href('preview');
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

So basically while working in localhost, without appending **`'#'`** it was just redirecting to

> localhost/preview

, instead of

> localhost/Project_Name/#/preview

I'm not taking here about passing the data, just to open $state in new tab.

Answer (score 6):

```
ui-sref="routeHere" href=""target="_blank"
```

this code solved my problem.

use this in an anchor tag.

Answer (score 4):

The best answered I found, was extending the ui.router, since the feature, does not exist build in.
You may find the full detail here :

**[Extending the Angular 1.x ui-router's $state.go](https://blog.entelect.co.za/view/10042/extending-the-angular-1-x-ui-router-s-state-go)**

However, here is my short explanation of what needs to be done add this to app.js or angular app init file:

```
angular.module("AppName").config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$state', ['$delegate', '$window',
        function ($delegate, $window) {
            var extended = {
                goNewTab: function (stateName, params) {
                    $window.open(
                        $delegate.href(stateName, params, { absolute: true }), '_blank');
                }
            };
            angular.extend($delegate, extended);
            return $delegate;
        }]);
}]);
```

**In your code**

You will be able to do:

```
$state.goNewTab('routeHere', { parameter1 : "parameter"});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this!

`<a ui-sref="routeHere({parameter: vm.parameter})" target="_blank"></a>`

Comment: This is irrelevant, I didn't say I need to add parameters to the route I call, I said I want to open this route in a new tab.

Comment: This may be relevant for many people. I just used this. One thing to mention here is that parameter name should be in  single quotes.  
<a ui-sref="routeHere({'parameter': vm.parameter})" target="_blank"></a>