# How to open $state,go() in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I am trying to open a state in newtab but not able to achieven it. I am doing so using $state,go function.

I tried the below code too which was succesful and opend my url in newtab but browser is blocking the opening of new url in new tab.

```
   openurlnw = $state.href('home.forward',{"url":$scope.platforms[0].url,"name":$scope.platforms[0].name,"dish_name":$scope.userSearchedDish});
   window.open(openurlnw,'_blank');
```

I want to open my state in new tab without letting the browser to block it.

Comment: Do you have an error message from your browser when it blocks the request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516289/angularjs-state-open-link-in-new-tab

Comment: no error it just show that browser prevented this site to open new pop-up window

Comment: Try `<a ng-href="{{ $state.href(...) }}" target="_blank">`. Browser will not block this and if you want this URL to be crawled that will also happen this way.

Comment: I have to implement it on to the JS part itself.

Comment: You may find the answer here [How to open $state,go() in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565518/1959948)

Answer (score 4):

You would have to use `absolute` option in constructing url, then just use `$window.open`

Replace:

```
openurlnw = $state.href('home.forward',{"url":$scope.platforms[0].url,"name":$scope.platforms[0].name,"dish_name":$scope.userSearchedDish});
```

With:

```
openurlnw = $state.href('home.forward',{"url":$scope.platforms[0].url,"name":$scope.platforms[0].name,"dish_name":$scope.userSearchedDish}, {absolute:true});
```

And Then:

```
$window.open(openurlnw,'_blank');
```

Comment: this is still not working .. same error  browser prevented this site to open new pop-up window

Comment: Actually, this is a functionality in all browsers. Specifically, to avoid opening multiple popups, maybe in a loop. You should open the popup window only after a user action, and it won't be blocked.