# ng-click new tab link with object params

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a link and I'd like to open the link in the new tab. The problem is : I send object parameters.

HTML :

```
<a ng-click="go(row)" ></a>
```

JS :

```
$state.go('link', {
  'search': {
    'obj': {
      'id': something
    }
  }
});
```

I have already tried href and ng-href without success.
Thank you.

Comment: Post the code for your go function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23516289/5413314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this to open it in new tab using a controller function for `go(row)` like

```
$scope.go = function(row){
  var param = {
  'search': {
    'obj': {
      'id': something
    }
  };

  var url = $state.href('link', {parameter: param });
  //open in new tab
  window.open(url,'_blank');
}
```

and then access the parameter in your controller like this

```
$stateParams.parameter
```

and value should be

```
{
 'search': {
   'obj': {
     'id': something
      }
}
```