# SPA open page on new tab

Tags: angularjs

I have an old system and for example the user can do a click-right new table on some link and in new tab the system will be open in same page, but now I built a new system SPA with angularjs and my users want the same funcionality but always that I open new tab the system open in the main page, of course is a SPA and the system not sabe the context.
I think that I need create a storage to create this, but will be a good practices?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516289/angularjs-state-open-link-in-new-tab

Comment: In your example is to always open in a new tab, but in my case I need just when the user click the right mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work only on right click then use the below function on ng-mousedown with passing $event to it. check the right click event & then open state in new tab.

```
$scope.openInNewTab = function(e){
    //console.log(e.button);
    if(e.button === 2) {
        var url = $state.href('PageTab.Page2', {});
        window.open(url,'_blank');
    }
}
<p ng-mousedown="openInNewTab($event)">Open page 2 in new tab</p>
```

Here's working plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/mo96eXMLKfHkUWPKPG2m?p=preview

Comment: Sounds Good!
But in this example You used the pages in URL in my case I use hide, I show just the domain all the pages run under of "/" and with this example not work

Comment: How are you using routing in your application? (Are you using $routeProvider or $stateProvider to define routes? Or you haven't implemented routing?)

Comment: $stateProvider
.state('fornecimento/info', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/fornecimento/info.html',
            params: {
                IDF: null,
                Contrato: null
            }
        })

Comment: So you've separate state for this purpose right? (to open in new tab)?
In my answer $state.href('PageTab.Page2, {}'), PageTab.Page2 is the state name it's not a path name.. So even if you've '/' path for all your states this solution should work

Comment: Yes, can be! I am thinking in to do this, but the parameters not work in new tab. I try to test in your example but also not work. I pass the parameters but in new tab not take.