# Angularjs $state.go open link in new tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My code looks something like this and there is data-ng-click for anchor tag.

```
$state.go('routeHere', {parameter : "parameter"} });
```

I have tried

```
var url = $state.go('myroute', {parameter: "parameter"});
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

**target="_blank"**

But those are not working.

Is there any other way to do that using AngularJS?

Comment: Angular isn't AngularJS, use the correct tags next time please.

Comment: You may find the answer here [Angularjs $state.go open link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565518/1959948)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you tried, but here's **[a working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/kN3JyRjlhJsrJtBvnya1?p=preview)**.

```
myApp.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, $state, $window) {
  $scope.newTab = function() {
   var url = $state.href('about');
   $window.open(url,'_blank');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hai @zooly thanks for the reply. I have tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Please can you provide more informations about your issue? I'm afraid that saying "It's not working" is not enough

Comment: This is the html tag I have 
<a class="video_link" data-ng-click="redirectTo(activity.video.type, activity.video.id)">

This is the js file:
      $scope.redirectTo = function(type, id) {
          $state.go('checkpreview', {a: id});
      }
@zooly

Comment: You need to add `$window.open(<url>,, '_blank');`

Comment: $scope.redirectTo = function(type, id) {
var url = $state.go('checkpreview', {a: id}); 
$window.open(url,'_blank');
}
@zooly Yes added and tried.No luck.

Comment: @anil, the working example is $state.herf, but your code used $state.go ... there are just two lines of code, man.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem with your solution is that you are using the wrong method on `$state`. Use `$state.href` instead of `$state.go`. That way `$state` will compile the URL for you and place in the variable `url` to use in the call to `$window.open`.

Correct code should be:

```
var url = $state.href('myroute', {parameter: "parameter"});
$window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Also, use `$window` instead of just `window`

Answer (score 0):

$state.go is working but you can use also 
$window.location.href = newUrl;

Answer (score 0):

Works for me :

```
href="{{$state.href(ng_state, {id : ng_id})}}" target="_blank"
```